# Arrange/align text from command

Tags: moderncv

I'm a \LaTeX beginner and would like to know how I could rearrange the text defined by the following command:

```
\newcommand \schickesDatum[2]{%
{\parbox[t]{\datumsZellenBreite}{\centering{#2\baselineskip=\datumsZifferMonatsAbstand\newline\par\vspace{\datumsZifferMonatsAbstand}\tiny{\strut#1}}}}%
}

\def \seit[#1.#2]#3{#3 \schickesDatum{\monthname[#1]}{#2}}
```

When used

```
\eintragL{\seit[06.2016]since}{Test}{Mitglied}{Berlin}{\begin{itemize}
    \item Test
\end{itemize}}
```

it looks like that:

[image]

[EDIT]: But the `since` should be left from the date. As seen here at  *Fundação*:

[image]
The code comes from this [github repository](https://github.com/Stefanqn/Bewerbung).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! It is not clear, what is your exact question. Please, try to clearly explain your problem and add a compilable code (a Minimal Working Example)

Comment: I linked the git repo above, but the template files are quite big. If I still need to provide a working example, I'd do that tomorrow.

Comment: For me, it's still unclear what you want, so please work on your question if you want to get some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer myself:

```
\eintragL{\seit[06.2016]{{\small seit} \hphantom{--}}}{Test}{Mitglied}{Berlin}{\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}}
```